# Неправильно работают методы

Tags: java

Ребята, выручайте, методы не работают правильно почему-то. Геттеры и Сеттеры классов Автор и Сообщение работают исправно, они прошли тест.. Описание ошибок методов в заголовках методов

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Callboard {

private Author [] authors;
private Message [] messages;

public Callboard() {
authors = new Author [0];
messages = new Message [0];
}
Метод тоже не работает вместо true выдает false
/* --Метод SaveMassage сохраняет отправленное сообщение и возвращает true обратно если пользователь был ранее зарегистрирован,
если нет, то метод не сохраняет сообщение и возвращает false; */
public boolean saveMassage(Message message) {
return message == null ? false : regUser(message.getAuthor());
}


При регистрации нового пользователя должно выводить true, а выводит false.
/* --Метод regUser сохраняет отправленного пользователя и возвращает true, если ни один другой пользователь с подобным именем
не был зарегистрирован до этого. В противном случае метод не сохраняет пользователя и возвращает false. */
public boolean regUser(Author author) {
Author findUser = author == null ? null : findUser(author.getName());
if (findUser == null) return false;
else {
authors = Arrays.copyOf(authors, authors.length+1);
authors[authors.length-1] = findUser;
return true;
}
}

При вызове пользователя ранее зарегистрированного выводит null, но не должно потому-что он уже зареган
/* -- Метод findUser ищет пользователя с заданным именем зарегистрированного ранее" на доске обьявлений" и возвращает этого пользователя.
Если пользователь с таким именем не существует, то метод возвращает null обратно. */
public Author findUser(String name) {
return Arrays.stream(authors)
.filter(author->author.getName().equals(name))
.findAny().orElse(null);
}
метод работает не правильно, должно сохранено, например, 3 сообщения, а выводит 0.
/* -- Метод findMassages для поиска сообщений. Этот метод возвращает массив хранимых сообщений, чья тема или сообщение содержит
переданную строку поиска (в качестве подстроки)(полу-String). Написание с большой или маленькой буквы должно быть проигнориванно.
Если ни одно сообщение не удовлетворяет ранее упомянотому критерию, то метод должен вернуть пустой массив(не null)(Просто пустой массив). */
public Message[] findMassages(final String str) {
return Arrays.stream(messages)
.filter(message->message.getTheme().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase()))
.toArray(Message[]::new);
}

Методы почему-то не подсчитывают количество пользователей и сообщений, но почему?
/* -Методы возвращают количество сообщений соответственно зарегистрированных пользователей. */
public int cMassages() {
return messages.length;
}

public int cAutors() {
return authors.length;
}
}
```

Comment: Поставил минус просто за плохое оформление и неуважение к отвечающим.

Comment: Вот это ты Ванга, но какая-то плохая! Я спал за 2 суток 2 часа от силы, сам сделай вывод на сколько мне хочется вести с тобой дискуссию  о том, что тебе кажется! Можешь позвать еще кого-то, пусть влепят еще минусов за то, что тебе кажется..

Comment: Вам" - так будет правильнее при обращении к незнакомым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* --Метод SaveMassage сохраняет отправленное сообщение и возвращает true 
     обратно если пользователь был ранее зарегистрирован,
     если нет, то метод не сохраняет сообщение и возвращает false; */
public boolean saveMassage(Message message) {
    return message == null ? false : regUser(message.getAuthor());
}
```

Покажите мне, где в этом методе сохраняется сообщение.

---

*Пожалуйста, переименуйте все Ваши "массажи" в "сообщения".*